# Error: Could not find or load main class(Java)

Tags: ubuntu, java, compile, jdk

I am using java in ubuntu machine. I can run java program from my eclipse. But I have some work that that I have to perform from command prompt. I could compile java program using javac `HelloWorld.java` command and its create the  `HelloWorld.class` in same directory. But when I run java HelloWorld command its gives me following error.

> Error: Could not find or load main class

I dont know why???

can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you CLASSPATH. It should contain current directory (aka ".").

Comment: when I echo $CLASSPATH it shows the following path
/opt/lucene-3.5.0/lucene-core-3.5.0.jar:/opt/lucene-3.5.0/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.5.0.jar:/opt/semanticvectors/semanticvectors-3.2.jar   and when i echo $JAVA_HOME it shows
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Comment: Then add '.' to your $CLASSPATH with `CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH` or as a paramater with `java -classpath .:$CLASSPATH HelloWorld`

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly create a **main** method in your java file, did you name the java file exactly like the class?

```
$ cat HelloWorld.java

public class HelloWorld {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("Bonjour le monde !");

        }

}

$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ java HelloWorld
Bonjour le monde !
```

Answer (score 0):

I was executing

`java HelloWorld.class`

instead of

`java HelloWorld`

Problem Solved!